# What is the relationship between fear and desire?

Tags: motivation, fear

Are fear and desire located on the opposite sides of a spectrum or are they more like filters/lenses through which one can look simultaneously?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Atlas of personality, emotion and behaviour (Mobbs, 2020) is able to visualise emotions in two dimensions: affiliation and dominance.  Fear is considered submissive and disaffiliative.  Desire is more dominant and intrapersonal, that is, in itself neither affiliative or disaffiliative.

[image: Emotions Fear and Desire]

**Reference**

Mobbs AED (2020) An atlas of personality, emotion and behaviour. PLOS ONE 15(1): e0227877. https://doi.org/10.1371/journal.pone.0227877

**Declared interest**

I am the author of the atlas paper.

Comment: The graph is really interesting, but as someone not super familiar with these concepts it's difficult to really understand how they relate just from the graph and short description.

Could you expand a little more on the relationship between fear and desire as you understand it and in relationship to the original poster's questin?